# JavaFX Scene Builder path in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx, scenebuilder

Can anyone please tell me where I can find the path to the correct files for Scene Builder on Ubuntu to get it linked in my preferences with Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 18):

if you installed Scene builder through ubuntu Software Center then the path should be "/opt/SceneBuilder/"

http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2013/01/31/java-fx-eclipse-ubuntu/preferences-_185/

Answer (score 16):

1. Start Scene Builder
2. Show the path of the executable by running the following command in terminal

   ps aux | grep Scene

Output:
user        9386  9.2  3.0 5422044 245152 ?      Sl   11:38   0:12 /opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder
user        9525  0.0  0.0  15800   932 pts/2    S+   11:40   0:00 grep --color=auto Scene

The last string in the first line of the output is the path of the executable. This should work regardless of how you installed Scene Builder (Ubuntu Software Center, Jar, RPM or DEB package).

Answer (score 5):

select these path in your IDE `opt/SceneBuilder`

Answer (score 4):

For  Ubuntu 20.04. Run File is in this below path..

`/opt/scenebuilder/bin/SceneBuilder`

(check your path) Your's will close or same.

Set this by clicking on Windows>> Preference and then JavaFx in Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

The default path is "opt/SceneBuilder"